# How to provide parameters in query for springboot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am writing an application in Spring Boot which queries my Oracle database for data. The query should accept start date and end date as input parameters. Below is the last part of my query and I would need both dates accepted as a parameter.

```
AND TRUNC(startDate) >= '18-January-2018'
AND TRUNC(startEnddate) <= '28-March-2018'
```

How can I obtain this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use spring jdbc, it simplifies querying databases.

Here is a link of a course to start with:
[www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate)